# Possible to disable jQuery for IE6?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-6

I've tried to be sneaky and set a var in an IE6 conditional comment; then use an if (is IE6) { do nothing } else { do these effects }; to no avail.

It was ignoring my calls to show/hide. I saw a few things where IE6 sucks with show/hide, so I tried adding hide/show classes to no avail as well.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and finish off my IE debugging.

http://paste.pocoo.org/show/234287/

**Bonus Points:** If you can explain how to get my portfolio section to show up in IE6 in the first place. :(
Entire page: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/234301/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to then jQuery has methods for browser sniffing. See [.browser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/).

e.g

```
if($.browser.msie && parseFloat($.browser.version) < 7){
```

**However**, browser sniffing is frowned upon these days, the preferred method is to use [.support](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/) to test if the browser supports a piece of functionality rather than test for   specific browser version(s).